# Парсинг цифр из строки

Tags: php

Есть переменная:

```
$str = "Привет народ, 14"; // Or $str = "Привет 14 народ";
```

Как осуществить парсинг числа из строки, при условии что число в строке только одно, но находиться в любой части строке.

Comment: регуляркой `~\d+~`

Comment: @Эдуард Если возможно, покажите пример

Comment: preg_match( '~\d+~' , $str , $title); 
Вопрос решен, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант такой вот извращенный способ

```
$m = "Привет, народ 14";

foreach (explode(' ', $m) as $s) {
    if(is_numeric($s)) {
        var_dump($s);
    }
}
```